# ImportError: Shell script to start Gunicorn fails to find module

Tags: django, bash, shell, gunicorn

Given the following folder structure for an "productsapi" application based on [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

```
/webapps/
└── projects
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── django-admin
    │   ├── django-admin.py
    │   ├── easy_install
    │   ├── easy_install-2.7
    │   ├── gunicorn
    │   ├── gunicorn_django
    │   ├── gunicorn_paster
    │   ├── gunicorn_start.sh
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip2
    │   ├── pip2.7
    │   ├── python
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── local
    ├── logs
    ├── run
    ├── static
    └── productsapi
        ├── products
        ├── manage.py
        ├── requirements.txt
        └── productsapi
```

For this I would like to prepare a [start script for gunicorn as described an article from 2013](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). I came up with the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

NAME="productsapi"                           # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/projects/                 # Django project directory
USER=exampleuser                             # User to run as
GROUP=examplegroup                           # Group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                # Worker processes to spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=productsapi.settings  # Settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=productsapi.wsgi          # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ./../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should 
# not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ./bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER \
--group=$GROUP \
--bind=127.0.0.0:8080 \
--log-level=DEBUG \
--log-file=-
```

I start the script as follows:

```sh
$ /webapps/projects/bin/gunicorn_start.sh
```

This fails with the following error message:

> ImportError: No module named productsapi.wsgi

I looks like some paths are not set correctly.

I can however start the application server when I do the following (mind the different path):

```
$ cd /webapps/projects/productsapi
$ gunicorn productsapi.wsgi:application --user=exampleuser \
    --groups=exampleuser --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 --log-file=- --log-level DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, your DJANGODIR should be `/webapps/projects/productsapi`.

Basically, it should be the directory that has `manage.py`.

You'll need to change `./bin/` to `../bin` in your exec line.