# Getting a FATAL Exited too quickly error. Supervisor configuration

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, supervisord

I am getting this error when trying to configure Supervisor for a Django application on a VPS. So when I look at the error log it seems like it can't find the directory but I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

The path is:

/home/webconexus/portfolio

```
(portfolio) webconexus@wagtail-portfolio:~/portfolio$ sudo supervisorctl status
portfolio                        FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details
```

This is my gunicorn_start file:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="portfolio"
DIR=/home/webconexus/portfolio
USER=webconexus
GROUP=webconexus
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/webconexus/portfolio/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=portfolio.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=portfolio.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

This is my conf file:

```
[program:portfolio]
command=/home/webconexus/portfolio/bin/gunicorn_start
directory=/home/webconexus/portfolio
user=webconexus
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/webconexus/portfolio/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

The new error log:

```
    [2019-02-07 12:58:20 +0000] [3835] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'portfolio'
```

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately..

Comment: Please share the structure of `/home/webconexus/portfolio` directory.

Comment: What's inside of `bin` ?

Comment: `webconexus@wagtail-portfolio:~/portfolio/bin$ ls
activate      activate.fish     chardetect  django-admin     easy_install      gunicorn         gunicorn_start  pip3    __pycache__  python3    python-config  wagtail
activate.csh  activate_this.py  django      django-admin.py  easy_install-3.5  gunicorn_paster  pip             pip3.5  python       python3.5  unidecode      wheel`

Answer (score 0):

No need to go back to `..`

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="portfolio"
DIR=/home/webconexus/portfolio
USER=webconexus
GROUP=webconexus
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/webconexus/portfolio/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=portfolio.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=portfolio.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR 
source ./bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ./bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

Comment: I have updated answer, can you try once again with updated script

Comment: Check the error log stated in my original question, I updated it. It is now something completed different

Comment: can you add path of wsgi and settings file

Comment: I think you are facing issue something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170897/importerror-shell-script-to-start-gunicorn-fails-to-find-module